# Need very simple restriction to asp page

Tags: asp-classic

I have an asp site with one page I need to be inaccessible by direct url= www. mysite.com/form_success.asp. I need for that page to be accessible only by submitting the actual form on www.mysite.com/form.asp. This is not for security purposes at all but only to cut out bogus conversion tracking hits in adwords. I've searched around but can't find exactly what I'm looking for as it's not php or html pages so I thought I would ask here for help. Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. check that `Request.ServerVariables ("HTTP_REFERER")` is not empty and has valid domain name
2. you could pass some hidden parameter from page A to page B. On page B you going to check, does this hidden parameter is provided.
3. Perhaps using IIRF (https://iirf.codeplex.com/) also could help you -- you could direct link to page from other domain (it's similar to way #1, but it's handling before ASP processor)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this on top of the code in the page you want to protect:

```
<%
If UCase(Request.ServerVariables("Request_Method"))<>"POST" Then
    Response.Status = "403 Forbidden"
    Response.End()
End If
%>
```

The Server Variables collection contains the request method, which is "POST" when posting a form with `method="POST"` attribute. Just check for this, and you can easily restrict acceess.

Answer (score 0):

There are two valid answers here.  Another approach, and a common method to check for a form submission is to give your form submit button a name attribute - eg

```
<input type="submit" value="send" name="mysubmitbutton" />
```

Then in form_success.asp you could use something like

```
<%
If Request.Form("mysubmitbutton") <> "send" Then
  Response.Redirect("myhomepage.html")
End If
%>
```